# Excluded point topology proof.

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a non-empty set. And suppose $x_0 \in X$. let $\tau =$ $\{$ $X$ $\}$ $\cup$ $\{$ $A \subset X$ $:$ $x_0 \notin A$ $\}$

Show that $\tau$ is a topology on $X$.

(1) $X \in \tau$ by assumption. Note since $x_0 \notin \varnothing$ and $\varnothing \subset X$ it follows that $\varnothing \in \tau$.

(2) I would like help with regards to an arbitrary collection of sets.I would like to show their union is in $\tau$ may I have some help, please? I thought about breaking it into 4 cases.

(1) $U_i$ $=$  X for all $i\in I$

(2) $U_i$ $\neq X$ for all $I\in I$

(3) $U_i$ $\neq X$ for some I$\in I$

(4)$U_i$ $=X$ for some $I \in I$

how shall I proceed?

Comment: How could the union not contain $x_0$ as an element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have an arbitrary set $S$ of elements of $\tau$, then

- if $X\in S$, then the union of all elements of $S$ is $X$, which belongs to $\tau$;
- otherwise, since $x_0$ belongs to no element of $S$, then $x_0$ also does not belong to the union of all elements of $S$, and therefore that union belongs to $\tau$.

Comment: May you please elaborate on your second point? I don't see how you went from $X \notin S$ to $x_0$ belongs to no element of S.? Can't S have an element which is a subset of $X$ that contains $x_o$?

Comment: Since $x_0$ bolongs to no element of $S$; it connot belong to their union.

Comment: I understand. If I have a set X and a collection of subsets S of X, then the union of the elements of S is X iff X $\in S$ ?

Comment: By the way, thank you very much I appreciate it so so so so so much.

Comment: No. If $X=\{1,2\}$, and $S=\bigl\{\{1\},\{2\}\bigr\}$, then the union of the elements of $S$ is $X$, in spite of the fact that $X\notin S$.